# How to get url for custom image field

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I have currently created a custom field in CiviEvents to upload an image for my event. When viewing the eventinfo page I can see the image in a collapsible field which shows the thumbnail of the image and when I click on the image it enlarges in a popup box.

All I need is the actual custom field url that point to the image so I can theme it correctly on my template.

I've dug deep into the CustomDataView.tpl and come across {$element.field_value} but again this loads the custom field in the collapsible pane.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, CiviCRM does not expose uploaded files directly, but routes them through a php script which checks permissions before fetching the image. If you know the file id and the event id, then you can construct the url yourself:

yoursite.org?q=civicrm/file&reset=1&id=FILE_ID&eid=EVENT_ID

Comment: Is there a way to input the FILE_ID and EVENT_ID programically as for each event the uploaded picture would be different? Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you would need to use variables.

Comment: This is not right anymore, since a file hash is mandatory. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28754/get-url-of-custom-image-field