# Get URL of custom image field

Tags: civievent, api, php, urls

I would like to display pictures which are defined as custom "File" fields within an event. I currently to this by generating URLs having the following format:

```
MY_URL?q=civicrm/file&reset=1&id=FILE_ID&eid=EVENT_ID
```

There's another question that has been answered and can be seen [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/how-to-get-url-for-custom-image-field).

Using this worked, until CiviCRM recently introduced a security patch (i'm on version 5.10.3). Now, the picture urls have some sort of hash attached to them (the url contains `fcs=...`). Since that update, I can't display the pictures anymore.

Is there a standard, API way of getting images defined in custom fields? I know there's an Attachment API, but when I try to retrieve my file I get the following error:

```
{

"error_code": 0,
"entity": "Attachment",
"action": "get",
"is_error": 1,
"error_message": "Failed to run permission check: Unrecognized target entity table (civicrm_event)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how this bug was fixed elsewhere https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.pcpteams/pull/216

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Could you please explain how to get a file path including the new mandatory hash via the API? Just posting a link is not Stack Overflow best practice :-/

Answer (score 1):

The file hash is mandatory because of [CIVI-SA-2019-01](https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2019-01-weak-access-control-for-file-attachments). Now you have to use the attachments url, which is available via the API. To bypass the permission check, you have to add the parameter `check_permissions` with value `0` (available since [5.12](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/690)).

Keep in mind, that you should only use this parameter on trusted API calls!

```
 $result = civicrm_api3('Attachment', 'getvalue', [
  'return' => "url",
  'id' => 42, // attachment/file id
  'check_permissions' => 0
]);
```